# Elasticsearch filter for a field based on several terms matching on all of them

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to filter a list of employees based on programming language skills like C, C++, Java etc. I am using Elasticsearch DSL in Java to search based on **all of the terms**.

`termsQuery` returns data matching **any of the terms** : means if at least one terms matches, it selects the data

[image]

I tried to the following code to set `minimum_should_match` to `tags.length` to match all given tags as "**AND** operator" to filter data but failed.

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders
            .boolQuery()
            .must(
                    QueryBuilders
                            .termsQuery("tags",tags)
            )
            .minimumShouldMatch(tags.length);
```

I also tried to use `TermsSetQueryBuilder` to check list of terms but it throws exception : `minimum_should_match_field` not set

```
QueryBuilder query =
            QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                    .should(
                            new TermsSetQueryBuilder("tags", tags)
                    )
                    .minimumShouldMatch(tags.size());
```

Also, tried to set `minimum_should_match_field` in `TermsSetQuery`, but it only accepts **String**, not numeric value or percentage as mention [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html#query-dsl-minimum-should-match). Tried to set like
`minimum_should_match_field` = "2"  `minimum_should_match_field` = "100%"
even tried to `setMinimumShouldMatchScript`. Not working.

```
QueryBuilder query =
            QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                    .should(
                            new TermsSetQueryBuilder("tags", tags)
                                    .setMinimumShouldMatchField(tags.size())
                    )
                    .minimumShouldMatch(tags.size());
```

How can I filter for a field("tags") based on several terms("tags": ["JAVA", "C"]) matching on all of them?

**UPDATED**
My code looks like the following:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeesByFilters(List<String> terms) {

    int required_matches = terms.size();
    QueryBuilder query =
            QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                    .must(
                            new TermsSetQueryBuilder(
                                    "filters", terms)
                                    .setMinimumShouldMatchField("required_matches")
                    );

    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(query)
            .build();

    List<Employee> employees = elasticsearchRestTemplate
    .search(nativeSearchQuery, Employee.class)
    .stream().map(SearchHit -> SearchHit.getContent())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return employees;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simpaly use boolean query to get expected result:

```json
{   
    "query":{
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
               {"term" : { "tags" : "JAVA" }},
               {"term" : { "tags" : "C" }}
             ]
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Terms Set query is not working because you need to add one field something like `required_matches` and set number for the number of matching terms required to return a document while indexing document.

So your index document will be looks like something below:

```
{
  "name": "Jane Smith",
  "tags": [ "C", "JAVA" ],
  "required_matches": 2
}
```

And you query will be looks like below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "tags": {
        "terms": [ "JAVA", "C" ],
        "minimum_should_match_field": "required_matches"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you will be able to create Java code from this query.

**Updated:**

```java
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(new TermsSetQueryBuilder("tags", tags).setMinimumShouldMatchField("required_matches"));
```

**Updated 2:**

You can use `minimum_should_match_script` and provide the `params.num_terms` as script which will count number of terms you have given in query and match all the terms and return result.

Elasticsearch Query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "tags": {
        "terms": [
          "JAVA",
          "C"
        ],
        "minimum_should_match_script": {
          "source": "params.num_terms"
        },
        "boost": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Java code:

```java
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "params.num_terms", param);

        QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(new TermsSetQueryBuilder("tags", tags).setMinimumShouldMatchScript(script));
```

Comment: In case of first solution, filter tags will be dynamic: like a string array of tags or list of strings: in that case how to write the dsl?

Comment: In case of second solution, do I need to create this field "required_matches" in my model?  I tried creating one, but not worked. Can you guide me write the DSL in Java?

Comment: You are developing java code right, so in that you can iterate list of tags and create boolean query and execute to ES cluster. I will say second option is better because in first one if list of tags increase in query then it will impact your response time.

Comment: For second option, You need to put one field which have total number of value available in tags field while indexing itself. and that field which have totla values that you can use in termset query.

Comment: Please check the updated answer with Java code for second option.

Comment: I added my current code in the question. Using "required_matches" field, it still throws "reason":"failed to find minimum_should_match field [required_matches]","index_uuid":"5unJ-ztqR22XMoz4RsLTEA","index":"employee"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"employee","node":"clwQ-9iJRNCM6SFALd7Urw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"**failed to find minimum_should_match field [required_matches]**","index_uuid":"5unJ-ztqR22XMoz4RsLTEA","index":"employee"}}]},"status":400}

Comment: did you added `required_matches` field in your indexed document in Employee index? Please check my answer where i have given sampel elasticsearch document and how its looks. This error is occruing because your index document dont have `required_matches` field.

Comment: I am using Java Spring-boot. I annotated the Employee model/entity with **@Document(indexName = "employee")**. I didn't use any json file to index document. In such case where should I put the required_match variable? In the model/entity?

Comment: See you have already index some data right. so you need to updated your model/entity with the new field and when you create object of employee class at that time you need to set value of that field as count of tags. and then you need to reindex entire data. I am not that much expert in spring boot so not able to suggest more on this.

Comment: I need to match all given tags, so I need to set required_matches = "100%". Could you let me know, in such case what should be the type of required_matches?

Comment: @PrantaPalit Please check updated 2 which used `minimum_should_match_script` and that will resolved your issue. You need to just updated your query and no other change required.

Comment: Putting `param.put("num_terms", tags.size());` with update 2 @SagarPatel solved my issue. Its working fine. Thank you @SagarPatel

Comment: Great to hear that it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, my Java code (working version) looks like the following:

```
// Filtering data by a field("tags") based on several terms - matching on all of the terms
public List<Employee> getEmployeesByTags(List<String> tags) {
    // tags : string list of terms

    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    param.put("num_terms", tags.size());
    Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "params.num_terms", param);

    QueryBuilder query =
            QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                    .must(
                            new TermsSetQueryBuilder(
                                    "tags", tags)
                                    .setMinimumShouldMatchScript(script)
                    );

    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(query)
            .build();

    List<Employee> employees = elasticsearchRestTemplate
    .search(nativeSearchQuery, Employee.class)
    .stream().map(SearchHit -> SearchHit.getContent())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return employees;
}
```